# chisel 5.0.0-RC1 and chiseltest

Tags: sbt, chisel, chiseltest

I'm attempting to upgrade a chisel 3.6.0 project to 5.0.0-RC1, and according to the [docs](https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel#build-your-own-chisel-projects) it looks as though chiseltest is not recommended for new projects. On a hunch I did also try to add a dependency on `org.chipsalliance:chiseltest` (not knowing any better, just updating the previous version), and ofc that didn't work.

What is the recommended way to upgrade such a project? Are there any helpful docs on the subject that I've missed (seeing as I haven't found any)?

Comment: It's hard to follow the docs of the lib. Many links are broken. As you said, doesn't seem that there are new version of `chiseltest` for new version of `chisel`. Looks like the latest one is `0.6.0`. Checking [chiseltest repo](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest), seems that they have a `5.0.0-SNAPSHOT` version where they [added support for chisel 5](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest/pull/637). Not sure if that version was published to some artifactory repo or you must build it locally. Without knowing the setup of your project and what you want to achieve, is hard to make a suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of a couple days ago, a [PR](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chiseltest/pull/637) has appeared for chisel 5.0.0 support in chiseltest (thanks to [Gastón Schabas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7214091/gast%C3%B3n-schabas) for pointing this out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432675/chisel-5-0-0-rc1-and-chiseltest?noredirect=1#comment134797969_76432675)).

In my particular case, at the time of writing, it's enough to simply update the dependencies to point to `org.chipsalliance:chisel 5.0.0` and `edu.berkely.cs:chiseltest 5.0-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: And now there is a stable `chiseltest 5.0.0` release.